# Entity Framework--Filter Data At Load Time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I’m building an MVC3 application with form authentication and a single hierarchical entity.  The entity has a Region object as the “root” with several other objects.  It looks something like:

Region->Language->objectA->objectB
  Region->Application->….

Each user (other than administrators) is associated with single region.  I'd like to limit the data loaded to the entity based on the user’s region.  I’m not too familiar with EF.  Is this appropriate or is there a better approach?  How would I implement the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly filter the data returned via Entity Framework.  The code would look something like this:

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var filtered = (from r in ctx.Regions where SOME_CONDITIONS select r);
    // Do stuff with filtered (which is an IEnumerable<Region>)
}
```

Note that you may need to use `Include` to load related objects, e.g.

```
ctx.Regions.Include("Language").Include("Application")
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: With lazy load enabled, will entity only contain information for that region?  Interested from performance & security reasons.

Comment: It should.  Where conditions are translated into WHERE clauses in SQL to only return necessary data.  Note that, even with lazy loading enabled, using Include will prevent extra round trips to the DB if those classes are accessed after the initial fetch.  If the classes are used in the `where` clause I'm unsure if they will be automatically included or not.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. I did as you suggested.  Stepping thru the code shows that only appropriate, filtered data was loaded.